# JavaScript convert date format

Tags: javascript, date

how to convert this date `Thu, 16 Feb 2017 08:00:00 GMT` to new format like `hh:mm`

my code so far :

```
var start = new Date(this.props.item.start); // this props returns Thu, 16 Feb 2017 08:00:00 GMT
var dateStr = start.format("hh:mm")
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Please always remember to Google first. This is super trivial to look up.

Comment: This isn't parse related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for hours and minutes (`hh:mm`) you can use this:

```
var start = new Date(this.props.item.start); // this props returns Thu, 16 Feb 2017 08:00:00 GMT
var dateStr = start.getHours() + ':' + start.getMinutes();
```

Comment: The string is not consistent with the [*format specified in ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) so parsing is implementation dependent. If parsed correctly, it will be considered UTC+0000, the *get\** methods will return times adjusted for the host timezone offset, which will likely differ between hosts. Lastly, the OP appears to want zero padding, so it doesn't return the required format. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) is not recommended, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

If all you want to do is reformat the string, then just do that and avoid the vagaries of date parsing:

```js
function getTime(s) {
  return (s.match(/\d\d:\d\d/) || [])[0];
}

console.log(getTime('Thu, 16 Feb 2017 08:00:00 GMT'));
```